# How to find commands ran in a particular day from a particular username

Tags: linux, shell, unix, rhel

I am able to find out from **secure** log that who logged in from where using ssh.

And the **last** command also proved that.

Is there any why to find out what were the commands run in that ssh session?

Comment: You should find your path [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/559658/log-commands-executed-over-ssh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what had been executed in past by which user might not be possible as history command does not store the timestamp by default. You need to enable those things for future reference.

Add the following in /etc/profile

```
HISTSIZE=
HISTFILESIZE=
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
```

You can also enable the auditd which is a very rich application for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the `history` and in the user `~/.bash_history` if it exists.

The env variable `HISTTIMEFORMAT` must be set for that to something like :

`export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "` in order to get the time and date informations

Comment: ~/.bash_history does not contains the date and time. Only commands are there.